# Сравнить текущую дату с датой из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Есть дата в MySql Такого формата

```
1969-10-21
```

Как написать условия в Php что если текущая дата равно дате из БД то что то нужно делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = '1969-10-21';
if ($date == date('Y-m-d')){
   //делать что-то
}
```

это тебе надо?